# fitting of a parabole with gnuplot is wrong

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to fit a curve with a second degree function with gnuplot:

```
    FIT_START_LAMBDA=10
    a = 2.4*1e-2
    b = 161
    c= 5.51454
    f(x)=a*(x-b)**2+c
    fit f(x) "chisq" u ($1):($2) via a,b,c
    plot f(x) w l,"chisq" with points
```

But I am not getting a good fitting result:[image]
It says that the fitting has converged:

```
After 4 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 83.9134
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe your data isn't described properly by a parabola but has some third order contributions

Comment: if needed, post the data somewhere, it's quite hard to verify the result from the figure...